# MATLAB array2table not accepting + -

Tags: matlab, matrix, formatting

I have a variable `k` which is a `3 x 3` matrix of results that I would like to use as data for a table.

I have attempted to use:

`array2table(k, 'VariableNames', {'s+e' 't*e' 's/y'})`

But unfortunately, the `+`, `*` and `/` symbols do not work with this I really need to display this table more formally with column titles, could somebody describe a similar alternative?

Comment: `VariableNames`  must be valid MATLAB identifiers because they are used to [index the table](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html) (e.g. `mytable.var1`). A potential alternative could be to utilize the [`VariableDescriptions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tableproperties.html#property_variabledescriptions) property of the `table` object.

Comment: After searching, I found out printmat function actually is very similar to array2table and does the job for me. thanks for your help tho !